# What is the difference between "@Scripts.Render" and "<script>"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I want to know about the difference between `@Scripts.Render("~/something.js")` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="/something.js"></script>`.

Yes, I've already searched about this subject, but with no success. I think if `@Scripts.Render` exists isn't by chance.

### More details

What I'm meaning is: when I should use one or other and why.

Comment: Difference in terms of... how they're processed on the server I assume? On the client side they will be exactly the same.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just want to know the difference. Why I should use `@Scripts.Render` and why I should use `<script>`.

Comment: Yes, it is duplicated — I didn't found this question before. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Scripts.Render is used for bundling, if you bundle multiple scripts together and give them a name, then you can render them all together using this statement.

On debug mode, they'll render multiple  tags, and in production you can deploy a single bundled script. Debug mode is set true or false in the web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" ... />
```

[Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) is more about bundling.

Comment: Then, for just one script is "unuseful"?

Comment: if you have only one script in your project then you wont make use of the bundling, but you'll make use of the minification of that script.

Comment: Oh, got it! You answered my question. =)

Comment: Great to be of service :)

Answer (score 2):

Functionally, they both have the same result in your example. The `Scripts.Render` is part of the **System.Web.Optimization** namespace, which is included in the [Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/). As such, `Scripts.Render` also support JavaScript bundles (see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).