# ASP.Net MVC How to render script elements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Could anyone explain me the difference between:

`<script src="/Scripts/custom.js"></script>`

and (added tilde symbol)

`<script src="~/Scripts/custom.js"></script>`

and

`@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/custom.js")`

within an ASP.NET MVC application (mainly in Razor View code)?

I am [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701781/what-is-the-difference-between-script-render-and-script) that usually `@Scripts.Render` is used for bundling and minifying scripts. As you can see in my third example, I am not using `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/*")` on purpose because I am not making this question look like question that is about bundling. I would like to know what the best way would be for rendering (page specific) scripts. Is there any other significant reason to use one before another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src="/Scripts/custom.js"></script>
```

This is relative to the root of your site. It's expecting a custom.js file to be in a Scripts directory in the root of your site, ex: `example.com/Scripts/custom.js`

```
<script src="~/Scripts/custom.js"></script>
```

This is virtual root relative. If your site is hosted as a [virtual application in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis) (a sub application), then it will ensure that it looks for a custom.js file in the root of your virtual application, rather than the root of the parent site. So even if your site is hosted at `example.com/yoursite`, `~/Scripts/custom.js` will look for `example.com/yoursite/Scripts/custom.js` instead of `example.com/Scripts/custom.js`.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/custom.js")
```

This looks for the file at the same location as `<script src="~/Scripts/custom.js"></script>`, but is just using a Razor HTML Helper as a shorthand to generate the HTML markup.

Comment: So basically `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/custom.js")` is totally the same as `<script src="~/Scripts/custom.js"></script>`. There is no difference, except Razor syntax.

Comment: @broadband I think it's important to note that the tilde only works with Razor - it won't work if you have a raw HTML file and use the `<script src="~/Scripts/custom.js"></script>` syntax.

Comment: Yes, good point. If one would create `page.html` and included `<script src="~/Scripts/custom.js"></script>` it wouldn't work. Well, one could use `..\` or full url path.

Comment: Despite this difference, everything else is the same? I'm just looking for yes or no answer. I also tried running few examples and it seems to confirm the equality. I havent looked the source code yet.

Comment: @broadband Should be the same - just check the resulting HTML if you want to know for sure.